# "ambiguous" mapping from CLR to EDM

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4.3

I understand that Code First used to have a problem (or maybe still does) when you have two classes with the same name in different namespaces. I have found numerous posts about this. I have something a little... different?

Well, however they "fixed" it, they made it worse. I don't HAVE two classes with the same name, I have ONE class. I promise you, you are not seeing double. The class name that appears below is exactly the same, and there is not other classname.

The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Classname'. Previously found CLR type 'App.Domain.Classname', newly found CLR type 'App.Domain.Classname'.

I get this error repeated many times (for different class names) when I attempt to create a new controller with the Template "MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework."

Comment: In the error message both types seem to have the same name: 'App.Domain.Classname'. Do you happen to reference two versions of the same assembly and therefore all/most types are duplicate? Note that even if EF used namespaces to distinguish types when loading POCO entities it would not help you since in your case full type names are the same.

Comment: Yes. That's the whole point of my question. I DON'T have two versions. 
My "solution?" Give up & start over with a new project/ new database.

According to my records, I have spent a day & a half (12 hours) futzing with the sharp corners on this "timesaving" (which I think means "we saved a ton of time by not testing this at all before we released it") Code First system.

Comment: You did not provide any repro so it's hard to figure out how you ended up having duplicates - the exception message shows that you have duplicates and after starting over you did not have ones. This probably means that there was something in your project that caused the exception. I wonder for instance if you try using CodeFirst but at the same time have an edmx file in your project what caused generating duplicate entities from your edmx file. Also, being rude and commenting on testing efforts you have no idea about is very unprofessional especially if someone is trying to help you.

Comment: @Pawel I am having the same issue and can provide a repro - I'm just getting started on the PluralSight MVC4 course. All four POCO classes I've made exhibit the same problem and I'm not sure why. The project is here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxb9wuf664pjyoy/TheaterTools.7z

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace and the exact exception message? I would like to see what line of code I should start from and the type that causes the problem.

Comment: @Pawel I'm not sure I can stack trace that for you. The error occurs for me when I try to add a controller, choose Company for the Model and TheaterToolsDataContext for the Data Context class. The error is "Unable to retrieve metadata for Theatertools.Core.CompanyEntities.Company. Schema specified is not valid." Then for each class I have in core, I get an error like what was specified in this original case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having more than one edmx file in same module this problem will be occur. And even within those edmx it may have same kind of two entity was exist. This is framework issue from ef4. But it can be resolve by.changing the entity name manually.' Which was created by edmx generated. Or simple add one more dump column in any one.of the entity. In first way we should do more changes in all the entity class as well as reference entity class also.